# Website Transactions in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

Good Day,

I'm currently designing database structure for a website of mine. I need community assistance in one aspect only as I never did something similar.

Website will include three types of the payments:

1. Internal payments (Escrow kind payments). User can send payment to another user.
2. Deposits. Users add fund to their accounts.
3. Withdrawal. User can request a withdrawal. Money will be sent to their bank/PayPal account.

Basically, I need some tips to get the best design possible.

Here's what I'm thinking about:
`deposits` - this table will store info about deposits
`deposits_data` - this table will store info about deposit transaction (ex. data returned by PayPal IPN)
`payments` - table to store internal payments
`withdrawals` - table to store info about withdrawal request
`transactions` - table to store info about ALL transactions (with ENUM() field called type with following values possible: internal, deposit, withdrawal)

Please note that I have already a table `logs` to store every user action.

Unfortunately, I feel that my design approch is not the best possible in this aspect. Can you share some ideas/tips?

PS. Can I use a name "escrow" for internal payments or should I choose different name?

**Edit**
`DEPOSITS`, `PAYMENTS` and `WITHDRAWALS` tables store specific transaction details. `TRANSACTIONS` table stores only limited info - it's a kind of logs table - with a `details` field (which contains a text to display in user log section, ex: "User 1 sent you a payment for something")/

Of course I have users tables, etc.

Comment: i have same kind of database design scenario can you please tell me what kind of internal payment you are storing in payments table so that it can help me design my database.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use a name "escrow" for internal
>   payments or should I choose different
>   name?

Escrow has a specfic financial/legal meaning, which is different from how you seem to mean it:  "a written agreement (or property or money) delivered to a third party or put in trust by one party to a contract to be returned after fulfillment of some condition" ([source](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=escrow))

So choosing a different name seems like a good idea.

As for design, what data will DEPOSITS, PAYMENTS and WITHDRAWALS store which TRANSACTIONS won't?  Also, you need an ACCOUNTS table.  Or are you planning to just use your existing USERS table (I presume you have such a thing)?  You probably ought to have something for external parties, even if you only intend to support PayPal for the time being.

Comment: I'd like to post a comment but it was a bit too long so I edited my question. Thanks for your answer!